# jtds with SQL Server 2008 R2 - "socket write error"

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, jtds

We moved an old installation to a new hosting partner and now we're getting intermittent (now and then, days apart) "socket write errors" on a jdbc connection from an apache (6.0.20) to an SQL Server 2008 R2 (running on another host). We're using the current jTDS (1.2.5) jdbc drivers. The problems did not occur before the move.

An MS SQL Server specialist suggests the problems might be related to us running jTDS with MS Server 2008 R2.

Q: Can anybody support (or disprove) the theory that our problems are related to us using jTDS (and that we would be better off using MS JDBC drivers)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons this could happen depending on what your application is doing:

1. The SQL Server instance may have been stopped
2. The connection has timed out
3. In the case of binary data, the stream is reset.